# loops for calculating probability of values in an array

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, probability

uni is the array created by counting the unique values of an array

```
uni=cs.unique()
```

I have the unique values in an array like this

```
uni = array(['suggest', 'inform', 'discuss', 'sell_or_buy', 'get_information','entertain'], dtype=object)
```

I want to calculate the probability for naive bays so I gave to following as a loop

```
prob =[]

for i in uni:
    prob1 = cs.value_counts().i/cs.count()
    prob.append(prob1)
print(prob)
```

I got the following error

```
'Series' object has no attribute 'i'
```

where did I go wrong pls help me understand.

Comment: prob1 = cs.value_counts().i/cs.count(). This is the right code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use list.

```
prob =[]
#just an example
cs = ['suggest', 'suggest', 'inform', 'discuss', 'discuss', 'sell_or_buy', 'get_information','entertain']
uni = ['suggest', 'inform', 'discuss', 'sell_or_buy', 'get_information','entertain']
for i in uni:
    prob1 = cs.count(i)/len(cs)
    prob.append(prob1)
print(prob)
```

Output:
[image]